# Is there a way to optimize this script to run faster? I am getting the error "Exceeded maximum execution time"

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google App Scripts to import data from Spreadsheet #1 to Spreadsheet #2. But I am getting the error "Exceeded maximum execution time". What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to optimize the code?

**Script Logic**

- Create Array #1, for column B, on Spreadsheet #1, which contains Employee ID's
- Create Array #2, for column A, on Spreadsheet #2, which contains Employee ID's already imported.
- If Array #1 contains an ID not found in Array #2, append a new row on Spreadsheet #2 with the ID, email1, and email2 columns.

##### Spreadsheet #1 (Source)

- Contains duplicate data in rows.
- There are 50,000 rows currently with 100 new rows added daily.

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 200001 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Email2@example.com | Email1@example.com |  |  |  |
|  | 200001 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Email2@example.com | Email1@example.com |  |  |  |

##### Spreadsheet #2 (Destination)

- Contains non-duplicate rows.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200001 |  | Email2@example.com | Email1@example.com |

##### Working Script (for data less than 5,000 rows).

```js
// Source sheet settings
let sourceSheetId = '1qW5UDn0O*******************';
let sourceTab = 'Source';
let sourceColumn = 2;
let sourceEmail1Column = 20;
let sourceEmail2Column = 19;

// Destination sheet settings
let destinationTab = 'Destination';
let destinationColumn = 1;
let destinationEmail1Column = 2;
let destinationEmail2Column = 4;


function newEmployeeIds() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationTab);

  let sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSheetId);
  let sourceSheet = sourceSS.getSheetByName(sourceTab);

  let existingIdsArray = destinationSheet.getRange(2,destinationColumn,destinationSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  let existingIds = existingIdsArray.flat();

  let sourceIdArray = sourceSheet.getRange(2,sourceColumn,sourceSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  let sourceIds = [...new Set(sourceIdArray.flat())];

  let email1Array = sourceSheet.getRange(2,sourceEmail1Column,sourceSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  let email2Array = sourceSheet.getRange(2,sourceEmail1Column,sourceSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();

  for (i=0;i<sourceIds.length;i++){
    if (existingIds.indexOf(sourceIds[i]) == -1){
    let newRow = destinationSheet.getLastRow()+1;
    destinationSheet.getRange(newRow,destinationColumn).setValue(sourceIds[i]);
    let index = sourceIdArray.flat().indexOf(sourceIds[i]);
    destinationSheet.getRange(newRow,destinationEmail1Column).setValue(email1Array[index][0]);
    destinationSheet.getRange(newRow,destinationEmail2Column).setValue(email2Array[index][0]);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

In this case, how about the following modification? In this modification, at first, the values are retrieved from the source and destination sheets, and create an array for putting to the destination sheet, and put it to the sheet.

#### Modified script:

```js
function newEmployeeIds2() {
  const srcSheetName = 'Source';
  const dstSheetName = 'Destination';
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [srcSheet, dstSheet] = [srcSheetName, dstSheetName].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));

  // Retrieve values from source sheet.
  const srcValues = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Retrieve values from destination sheet and create an object for searching the ID.
  const dstLastRow = dstSheet.getLastRow();
  const dstObj = dstSheet.getRange("A1:A" + dstLastRow).getValues().reduce((o, [a]) => (o[a] = true, o), {});

  // Create an array for putting to the destination sheet.
  const values = srcValues.filter(r => !dstObj[r[1]]).map(r => [r[1], "", r[18], r[19]]);

  // Put the values to the destination sheet.
  dstSheet.getRange(dstLastRow + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

### Added:

From your following replying,

> Unfortunately I am receiving the error "Cannot read property 'getDataRange' of null (const srcValues = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();)". I believe this is because your code assumes the source and destination sheet are in the same Spreadsheet. In reality, the source sheet is in a different spreadsheet. I tried changing const srcSheetName = 'Source'; to const srcSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1qW5UDn0O*******************').getSheetByName('Source'); but still an error when running the code. Do you know whats wrong?

From your replying, I modified the script as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you run teh script, Please set the Spreadsheet ID1.

```js
function newEmployeeIds2() {
  const srcSheetName = 'Source';
  const dstSheetName = 'Destination';
  const srcSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetID1").getSheetByName(srcSheetName);

  const dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  // or const dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetID2).getSheetByName(dstSheetName);

  // Retrieve values from source sheet.
  const srcValues = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Retrieve values from destination sheet and create an object for searching the ID.
  const dstLastRow = dstSheet.getLastRow();
  const dstObj = dstLastRow == 0 ? {} : dstSheet.getRange("A1:A" + dstLastRow).getValues().reduce((o, [a]) => (o[a] = true, o), {});

  // Create an array for putting to the destination sheet.
  const values = srcValues.filter(r => !dstObj[r[1]]).map(r => [r[1], "", r[18], r[19]]);

  // Put the values to the destination sheet.
  dstSheet.getRange(dstLastRow + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thank you for taking the time to provide a solution. Unfortunately I am receiving the error "Cannot read property 'getDataRange' of null (const srcValues = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();)". I believe this is because your code assumes the source and destination sheet are in the same Spreadsheet. In reality, the source sheet is in a different spreadsheet. I tried changing `const srcSheetName = 'Source';` to `const srcSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1qW5UDn0O*******************').getSheetByName('Source');` but still an error when running the code. Do you know whats wrong?

Comment: @JamesReed68 Thank you for replying. I couldn't notice that you are using 2 Google Spreadsheets. I apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @JamesReed68 And also, I noticed that when the destination sheet has no values, an error occurs. So I modified it just now. Please confirm it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the revisions. Your updated script worked perfectly. I did make a small edit to your script. This was not your fault (I did not communicate that the source sheet has a header column). With your script it was also adding the header to the destination sheet. Here is what I added/modified `var headerRowNumber = 1;
  const srcValues = srcSheet.getDataRange().offset(headerRowNumber, 0, srcSheet.getLastRow() - headerRowNumber).getValues();`

Comment: Sorry I took so long to mark your answer is correct. Instead of me asking you to solve the header problem, I tried to research and solve it on my own. I don't know if its a good solution, but it works :D

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I am getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (line 37, file "Code")" [Line 37]  `dstSheet.getRange(dstLastRow + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);` I did some troubleshooting, and I discovered that... On first execution of script, its successful, this is because the destination sheet has no blank rows. Once the script executes, it also copies the black rows front the source sheet, and sends it to destination sheet. Now that destination has blank rows, the script fails with this error.

Comment: @JamesReed68 About your new issue, I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand your current situation. So can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, I would like to check your current situation. And also, it will help users think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: I can absolutely do that! It would be much cleaner. Sometimes I get down voted for creating a new topic instead of using the comments here. But I will do as you suggest.

Comment: @JamesReed68 I think that if the new question has detailed information, such a question will have worth it for other users who have the same issue. But if the same question has already been posted before, the question might be closed as the duplicated question. At that time, such a question is useful for the understanding of your question.