# Google App Script: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (line *, file "Code")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

##### The Goal

Prevent the script from copying blank (empty) rows from source to destination which is causing the error.

---

##### Error Details:

> Google App Script: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (line *, file "Code")

This error, refers to the line:
`dstSheet.getRange(dstLastRow + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);`

---

##### The full code

I am using the following code from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70690191/13255292) which has been slightly modified. The error occurs with and without the modification. The logic of the code is: If destination sheet does not contain ID, import ID, and specific columns from source to destination.

```
function importNewEmployeeIds() {
  const srcSheetName = 'Source';
  const dstSheetName = 'Destination';
  const srcSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetID1").getSheetByName(srcSheetName);

  const dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dstSheetName);

  // Retrieve values from source sheet.
  var headerRowNumber = 1;
  const srcValues = srcSheet.getDataRange().offset(headerRowNumber, 0, srcSheet.getLastRow() - headerRowNumber).getValues();

  // Retrieve values from destination sheet and create an object for searching the ID.
  const dstLastRow = dstSheet.getLastRow();
  const dstObj = dstLastRow == 0 ? {} : dstSheet.getRange("A1:A" + dstLastRow).getValues().reduce((o, [a]) => (o[a] = true, o), {});

  // Create an array for putting to the destination sheet.
  const values = srcValues.filter(r => !dstObj[r[1]]).map(r => [r[1], r[19], "", r[18]]);

  // Put the values to the destination sheet.
  dstSheet.getRange(dstLastRow + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

##### Troubleshooting

[Source] *Before* script is run.

```
|  A   |B|  C   |  D   |
|200001| |Email2|Email1|
|200001| |Email2|Email1|
|200006| |Email4|Email3|
|200007| |Email6|Email5|
|      | |      |      |
```

[Destination] *Before* script is run.

```
|  A   |B|  C   |  D   |
|200001| |Email2|Email1|
```

[Destination] *After* script is run.

```
|  A   |B|  C   |  D   |
|200001| |Email2|Email1|
|200006| |Email4|Email3|
|200007| |Email6|Email5|
|      | |      |      | <-- Notice the blank row. I don't want the blank row.
```

Once the script runs, it copies row data from source to destination. The problem is, the script will also copy the blank (empty) rows to the source sheet.

[Destination] *Expected Results* - No blank rows

```
|  A   |B|  C   |  D   |
|200001| |Email2|Email1|
|200006| |Email4|Email3|
|200007| |Email6|Email5|
```

---

##### Rookie Solutions that I can think of:

**Option A)** At the beginning of the script, I could first delete all empty rows from the destination. This is less efficient, and does not fix the root of the issue, but at least it fixes my problem.

```
function removeEmptyRows(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var maxRows = sh.getMaxRows(); 
  var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  if (maxRows-lastRow != 0){
    sh.deleteRows(lastRow+1, maxRows-lastRow);
    }
}
```

Code found: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26387265/13255292)

---

**Option B)** Update the original code so it does not copy the blank rows.

[BEFORE]

```
  const srcValues = srcSheet.getDataRange().offset(headerRowNumber, 0, srcSheet.getLastRow() - headerRowNumber).getValues();
```

[AFTER]

```
  const srcValuesAndBlankRows = srcSheet.getDataRange().offset(headerRowNumber, 0, srcSheet.getLastRow() - headerRowNumber).getValues();
  const srcValues = srcValuesAndBlankRows.filter(String); //Removes Blank Rows
```

Code Found: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/56856343/13255292)

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize. If my proposed script was not useful, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image? By this, I would like to modify the script.

Comment: @Tanaike I have revised my question so its shorter, and easier to understand. I added tables to showcase before script run, after script run, and expected results after script run. I hope this is easier to understand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, for example, how about the following modification? I modified 2 parts in the script.

#### Modified script:

```
function Q70718274_importNewEmployeeIds() {
  const srcSheetName = 'Source';
  const dstSheetName = 'Destination';
  const srcSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetID1").getSheetByName(srcSheetName);

  const dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dstSheetName);

  // Retrieve values from source sheet.
  var headerRowNumber = 1;
  const srcValues = srcSheet.getDataRange().offset(headerRowNumber, 0, srcSheet.getLastRow() - headerRowNumber).getValues().filter(r => r.join("") != ""); // <--- Modified

  // Retrieve values from destination sheet and create an object for searching the ID.
  const dstLastRow = dstSheet.getLastRow();
  const dstObj = dstLastRow == 0 ? {} : dstSheet.getRange("A1:A" + dstLastRow).getValues().reduce((o, [a]) => (o[a] = true, o), {});

  // Create an array for putting to the destination sheet.
  const values = srcValues.filter(r => !dstObj[r[1]]).map(r => [r[1], r[19], "", r[18]]);

  // Put the values to the destination sheet.
  if (values.length > 0) { // <--- Added
    dstSheet.getRange(dstLastRow + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
}
```

- By `const srcValues = srcSheet.getDataRange().offset(headerRowNumber, 0, srcSheet.getLastRow() - headerRowNumber).getValues().filter(r => r.join("") != "");`, the empty rows are removed.
- By `if (values.length > 0) {}`, when `values` has no values, no error occurs.

### Added:

From your following additional information,

[Source] *Before* script is run.

```
|  A   |B|  C   |  D   |
|200001| |Email2|Email1|
|200001| |Email2|Email1|
|200006| |Email4|Email3|
|200007| |Email6|Email5|
|      | |      |      |
```

[Destination] *Before* script is run.

```
|  A   |B|  C   |  D   |
|200001| |Email2|Email1|
```

[Destination] *After* script is run.

```
|  A   |B|  C   |  D   |
|200001| |Email2|Email1|
|200006| |Email4|Email3|
|200007| |Email6|Email5|
|      | |      |      | <-- Notice the blank row. I don't want the blank row.
```

Once the script runs, it copies row data from source to destination. The problem is, the script will also copy the blank (empty) rows to the source sheet.

[Destination] *Expected Results* - No blank rows

```
|  A   |B|  C   |  D   |
|200001| |Email2|Email1|
|200006| |Email4|Email3|
|200007| |Email6|Email5|
```

I understood that you want to achieve the bottom table from the top 2 tables. From your provided script, I had thought that you wanted to use `const values = srcValues.filter(r => !dstObj[r[1]]).map(r => [r[1], r[19], "", r[18]]);`. But, from your additional situations, I understood that my understanding was not correct. For your additional sample situation, how about the following script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function importNewEmployeeIds2() {
  const srcSheetName = 'Source';
  const dstSheetName = 'Destination';
  const srcSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetID1").getSheetByName(srcSheetName);

  const dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dstSheetName);

  // Retrieve values from source sheet.
  var headerRowNumber = 1;
  const srcValues = srcSheet.getDataRange().offset(headerRowNumber, 0, srcSheet.getLastRow() - headerRowNumber).getValues().filter(r => r.join("") != ""); // <--- Modified

  // Retrieve values from destination sheet and create an object for searching the ID.
  const dstLastRow = dstSheet.getLastRow();
  const dstObj = dstLastRow == 0 ? {} : dstSheet.getRange("A1:A" + dstLastRow).getValues().reduce((o, [a]) => (o[a] = true, o), {});

  // Create an array for putting to the destination sheet.
  // const values = srcValues.filter(r => !dstObj[r[1]]).map(r => [r[1], r[19], "", r[18]]);
  const values = srcValues.filter(r => !dstObj[r[0]]).map(r => [r[0], "", r[2], r[3]]); // <--- Modified

  // Put the values to the destination sheet.
  if (values.length > 0) { // <--- Added
    dstSheet.getRange(dstLastRow + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. `if (values.length > 0) {}` fixed the error which is good. But the empty rows are still being copied from source to destination using the new code `const srcValues = srcSheet.getDataRange().offset(headerRowNumber, 0, srcSheet.getLastRow() - headerRowNumber).getValues().filter(r => r.join("") != "");`

Comment: @JamesReed68 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your additional sample situation, I couldn't notice that you didn't want to use `const values = srcValues.filter(r => !dstObj[r[1]]).map(r => [r[1], r[19], "", r[18]]);`. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. For your additional sample situation, I added one more script. Could you please confirm it? If this was not the direct solution of your issue, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your issue including the script? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Thank you very much Tanaike for all your hard work. This was my fault, not your English. The issue is not with your script. When I created a sample spreadsheet to replicate the problem, your script works perfectly (there is no blank rows under the data). On my real spreadsheet, I am still having the problem (lots of blank rows under data). So I need to investigate what is wrong with it. Unfortunately we cannot learn together what's wrong with the real sheet because I cannot share the real spreadsheet due to privacy. But if I find the solution I will share it to help others. :)